# How to pass values from text area to table using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

C# MVC App using AngularJS

I am trying to display  a list of  values  in a table that were originally entered in a text area.

Here is the workflow

User enters  values in a text area as

```
A
B
C
```

When the user clicks on a button a modal window opens and should display A B C in a table .

I am trying to use angular to do this. I have tried the following:

```
<a class="btn btn-inverse pull-right" ng-click="arrangelist()">Arrange list</a>

<textarea id="letterlist" ng_model="letters"></textarea>
```

Also tried

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.letters, new { ng_model = "letters", @class = "width-100-percent", @rows = "7" })
```

And here is my modal window:

```
<div id=" arrangelist" class="modal hide fade" aria-hidden="true">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Letters</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-animate="'table-anim'" ng-repeat="letter in letters">
                <td>{{letter}}</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript that opens the window:

```
$scope. arrangelist = function() {
    return $('#arrangevideos').modal('show');
}
```

So the modal window opens and displays the table but no values are inside the table.

How can I pass the values from the text area to the table in the modal window using Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ng_model = "letters"` to `ng-model = "letters"`.

And letters should be an `array` instead of `string`. You have to split the input to list of strings.

```
$scope.arrangelist  = function() {
    var letterplits;
    letterplits = $('#letterlist').val().split('\n');
    $scope.letters = letterplits;
    return $('#arrangelist').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Thats an oversight by me. I changed it but the values from the text area still doesnt populate the table in the modal window

Comment: @Milligran The problem could be `letters` needs to be an array, you have to split the string typed in

Comment: Thanks. Thats it. converted to array

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `ng-model`, not `ng_model`. As long as your modal is in the same controller as your textarea, you should be able to pass it. Also, you have a space between `$scope.` and `arrangelist`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1213/) for a simple working example.